# Extern and Duplicate Symbols

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm building a recursive descent parser in C++ and am trying to define a map between characters and strings. However, when I try to compile, I get a duplicate symbol error.

Here's the code:

> parser.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

#ifndef PARSER_H
#define PARSER_H

extern std::map<char, std::string> tokens;

class Parser {
 public:
  Parser();
 private:

};

#endif
```

> parser.cc

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "parser.h"

std::map<char, std::string> tokens = {{'+', "PLUS"}, {'-', "MINUS"}, {'*', "STAR"}, {'/', "SLASH"}, {'(', "LPAR"}, {')', "RPAR"}};

Parser::Parser() 
{

}
```

> calculator.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include "parser.h"

int main()
{
    Parser RD_Parser;

    return 0;
}
```

When I issue make, I get this:

```
g++ -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 -g parser.o calculator.o -o Calculator
duplicate symbol _tokens in:
    parser.o
    calculator.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Calculator] Error 1
```

I'm guessing it has to do with the `extern` definition, but the examples I've looked at look quite similar to this. Any idea why this is being duplicated in `calculator.o`?

I'm using clang 3.4.2.

Comment: Works for me with `Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)`

Comment: Any chance you have a stale object file in there? Have you tried a clean build?

Comment: @Angew, I cleaned my project and it worked. I did this earlier and it didn't work. This is very interesting behavior.